# Why can't I boot off a USB device on my new PC without getting an error message?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, drivers

I have just built a PC and am trying to reinstall windows 7 ultimate after it installed in a corrupted state. Basically I was having a problem that was shown in [this](https://www.pntbrother.com/remove-client-exe-error-message-windows-cannot-find-cprogram-filesx86search-extensionsclient-exe/) thread but I was unable to access the 'Tasks' folder because it would not open no matter how many times I have tried to open it. - If you have a fix for this please let me know as then I will have no need to reinstall windows.

So your probably wondering how I got windows on my PC in the first place. Well it's a long story. So the first time that I booted I managed to boot of the USB but it took a very long time.

Then I had to reinstall because I installed all the drivers to the wrong HDD.

When reinstalling, I used the disk as I could now use the CD rom as the drivers were installed.

I am now at the current point in time where I need to reinstall. This is because of the above issue, and because I did the fresh install earlier I can not use the CD ROM and I can not install the drivers for the CD ROM because I get the error which I linked earlier.

So yeah, I am here now with a CD that I can not use because no drivers are installed, and a USB stick that for some reason my PC will not boot from.

The ISO I am flashing to the USB is not the one from the disk. It is one that my friend took from his windows 7 disk and gave to me on a USB so that I could install it onto parallels desktop on my MAC (I purchased a serial number).

The error I am given when I try to boot is:

`reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key`

I have reflashed the ISO to different USBs. I have also used different software to to is as well as Terminal in my mac. None of these have worked. I have also tried to boot different OS and these haven't worked either.

The motherboard I have is a MSI Z97 MPOWER Intel Socket 1150.

I am honestly stuck for idea on what to do. I have read so many different threads, none of them have been able to solve my issue.

Just so there are no repeats, here is what I have already tried:

- Different Software to flash ISO to memory stick
- Different Memory Stick
- Different ISO
- I am almost certain I am in the right boot order

Just thought that I would mention that on loads of threads people said I should turn off secure boot but I have searched and am unable to find this in the BIOS. If you know where this would be located then please let me know and I can confirm that it is disabled.

Thanks very much!

Comment: how are you writing the iso to usb?  also i'd suggest you try other ways e.g. unetbootin

Comment: Check my edit to the answer below, use F11 to get the boot menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a SATA CD drive, you shouldn't need any drivers. It sounds like your motherboard just doens't want to install with a USB. My motherboard had the same problem when I tried to install Windows 7, despite the company saying it would work. Just burn the ISO onto a `blank DVD` using PowerISO and put it in a SATA DVD drive and then boot your PC. It should attempt to load from the DVD. Windows 7 is easy to install as it has a very visually based installer. From there you can just choose your hard drive, change your partitions and stuff.

On boot at the splash screen you can press the F11 key to access your MSI boot menu. From there you should be able to select your usb drive to boot from.

If all else fails, chances are you have a really dodgey ISO and should acquire a new one

Comment: My CD drive is USB. Therefore I can not use it until the drivers are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a while I discovered the problem.

The issue was with the memory stick that I was using. I installed Ubuntu onto the USB and booted successfully off that so I knew that it was not an issue with the PC. I found that that what fixed my problem was to format the memory stick to NTFS. It is important that you uptick the 'quick format' box if using windows. I formatted the memory stick plenty of times but was only able to boot from it when the box had been untucked and I re-flashed the ISO to the memory stick using the 'Windows USB tool' that can be downloaded by clicking [here](http://wudt.codeplex.com/#).

Hope that this is helpful to anyone else having issues!